# Best Practise for Openshift Origin Authentication

Tags: authentication, openshift-origin

I am introducing Openshift at the moment for one of my customers because it seems to fit perfectly to their needs. Everything works like a charm but at the moment, I still have configured the AllowAllPasswordIdentityProvider (https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/admin_guide/configuring_authentication.html#AllowAllPasswordIdentityProvider) and this is highly unsecure. Therefore, I am searching for best practises of integrating my own authentication provider. I know that there are multiple options. Currently, the most reasonable ones are for me:

- HTPasswd
- Basic Authentication
- LDAP

I read that some people use KeyStone authentication (https://github.com/openstack/keystone) or implemented their own Basic or HTPasswd application. I would like to use an existing one (if possible optimised for Openshift) and therefore, I want to ask whether there is a tool, which would fit perfect to this use case (or you maybe use for production).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your choice for Openshift authentication should depend on what your customer is already using to manage users.  For example, if they use Kerberos in a Linux environment, you could set up an Apache based proxy to allow SSO via `oc`.